# Outlook Addin - Unloaded

Tags: c#, outlook, wix, add-in, outlook-addin

I have an outlook plugin created in .net 2012 [using vsto for .net 4.0]
The plugin works fine in or release mode.

when using the wix installer and install the plugin, it is always in unloaded mode. 
the start up type in registry is intially 3 [when the plugin is installed] but when outlook is started it changes to 0. Tried Fuslog, NDepend to figure out the missing dependency...but no luck.

IS there any way to check the exception? BTW, the application referes to 15 dlls and an Exe [created] without manifest

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your VSTO log file?

You can do this by adding the following system environment variable:

> NAME: VSTO_LOGALERTS
>
> VALUE: 1

Or you can display each error in a message box, by setting the following system environment variable:

> NAME: VSTO_SUPPRESSDISPLAYALERTS
>
> VALUE: 0